# Cómo recoger fecha y hora con angular y firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, date, timestamp

Estoy haciendo una web en angular con la base de datos en firebase y quiero saber cómo puedo recoger fecha y hora. También quiero saber como puedo darle formato luego para mostrarlo en la web...

Ahora mismo en una parte de la aplicación tengo un date-picker con el que recojo la fecha y la guardo como timestamp en firebase:

HTML:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="date" formControlName="fecha" (click)="date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #date disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

FIREBASE:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego a la hora de mostrar la fecha no consigo darle formato... En firebase me aparece como por ejemplo 15 Diciembre 2020 y no consigo darle luego ese formato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otro lado de la aplicación estoy recogiendo la fecha y hora así:
HTML:

```
<mat-label>{{ 'prensa.fecha' | translate }}</mat-label>
<input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="fecha" disabled>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto me lo guarda en firebase como un string: "2020-12-15T23:20"

La cuestión es que quiero saber como puedo sacar un date-picker en el que tengan que escoger fecha y hora (la segunda opción si me la muestra en algunos navegadores) y luego saber como darle formato para que me aparezca como "15 de diciembre de 2020, 22:30"

Comment: Es probable que en tu ".ts", te esté faltando especificar un modelo con una clase ExportInterface dentro, donde puedas especificar los tipos de cada uno de los datos que vas a guardar. Si ya tienes un model sería mover ahí nada más el tipo del campo fecha para que lo guarde correctamente

Comment: Te lo guarda de esa forma, por que lo guarda en un formato Json, te recomiendo usar MomentJs, para parsear tu fecha , y para darle formato.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea en primer lugar quería saber si con mat date picker se puede añadir alguna opción para incluir la hora y recoger ese valor. Por otro lado, como sería para recoger la fecha con MomentJs?